# Should I encapsulate internal server errors into SOAP faults?

Tags: soap, internal-server-error

Say, the database is unavailable -- should I respond just with code 500 or it would be better to return a SOAP fault message with something like "Service unavailable"?

What is the best practice for that matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, it should be a SOAP Fault.  This is a nice thing to do for developers who are consuming your API.

Most SOAP client libraries in various languages will treat this as an `exception`, which will allow developers to wrap a SOAP call in a `try/catch` block.  It shouldn't be necessary for a developer to detect HTTP response codes with SOAP.

Also, some SOAP servers will return faults with status code 500 already.  You might find your language does this automatically when you respond with a SOAP Fault.